# Why are expression constructors hidden in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently looking at building something that closely follows the way .Net creates expressions and I'm looking at the `Expressions` class in `Linq`, and I'm quite confused as to why they went down the route of `Expression.Call(Params)` over something like `new CallExpression(Params)`?

My first guess is readability or the fact they are hiding the real class definition from you making it more future resilient.

Comment: One of the most obvious reasons is that using a factory method allows for generic type parameter inference. I suppose there may be other architectural motivations as well, but type inference helps keep `Expression`-based code from being even more verbose than it already necessarily is.

Comment: In some scenarios it may be useful to return an internal subtype of the declared return type. For example, `Expression.Field` returns a `FieldExpression` but that type is not public. That kind of indirection is not possible if users are directly instantiating concrete classes. Furthermore, since that is an implementation detail it can change in the future. This is going to boil down to what are the benefits of a static factory/facade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the source using a decompiler you will find that the calls look like this:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static MethodCallExpression Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable<Expression> arguments)
{
  ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull((object) method, "method");
  ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments1 = CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly<Expression>(arguments);
  Expression.ValidateMethodInfo(method);
  Expression.ValidateStaticOrInstanceMethod(instance, method);
  Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes((MethodBase) method, ExpressionType.Call, ref arguments1);
  if (instance == null)
    return (MethodCallExpression) new MethodCallExpressionN(method, (IList<Expression>) arguments1);
  return (MethodCallExpression) new InstanceMethodCallExpressionN(method, instance, (IList<Expression>) arguments1);
}
```

You'll notice that even though the call type is `MethodCallExpression` the actual returned types in the method are `MethodCallExpressionN` & `InstanceMethodCallExpressionN`. The two are internal subclasses of `MethodCallExpression`.

So, the static methods enforce the correct logic to return the right types, based on the arguments given. You wouldn't get that if you were able to call the constructors directly.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, I can't believe I didn't think about decompiling it, herp derp.